# How can i write a wrapper class for any library?

Tags: java, c#, .net, oop, wrapper

I am C# developer. I want to use some libraries but these libraries use another languages. For example https://neo4j.com

There are some Client library that use neo4j in C#. But this is just an example to tell you of my intentions. For example; http://vertx.io/. I have found some libraries, but i want to develop it myself.

[image]

Comment: The process of "translating" a library in one language to another is called _porting_. What library exactly do you want to port?

Comment: http://jni4net.com/